# Getting json data with Angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the following code that I am trying to use to pull in json data via a url. The data is not populating. Where am I going wrong? I have tried multiple options but none of them are working so I ma putting in my base code and the json url I need to get the data from. Security controller is where I need to put this code into

```
var urvirl = angular.module('urvirl', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'fragments/homepage.html',
    controller: 'homepageController'
  }).
  when('/security-profile/', {
    templateUrl: 'fragments/my-account.html',
    controller: 'securityController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);


var urvirl_controllers = angular.module('urvirl.controllers', ['ngRoute']);

urvirl_controllers.
     controller('securityController', ['$scope', '$route', '$window',
    function ($scope, $route, $window,) {

     }]);
```

And the url is here:

```
$http.get('http://ec2-54-68-150-129.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/urvirl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/user/5')
```

Comment: Check your console for errors..

Comment: please make a plunkr or equivalent so that we can see the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

This was the data I get from going to that url:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "userID": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "screenName": null,
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "homePhone": null,
  "workPhone": null,
  "homeEmail": null,
  "workEmail": null,
  "cityLocation": null,
  "workLocation": null,
  "countryID": null,
  "birthDate": null
}
```

So looks like the server might not be returning valid information. Where are you doing the get call? Use the developer tools in chrome / firefox / IE to check if its even making the http call to the server, and what response its getting back (both headers and body)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `'urvirl.controllers'` module as a dependency for the `'urvirl'` module:

```
var urvirl = angular.module('urvirl', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','urvirl.controllers']).
// ...
```